# Colorize $3D$ "random walk" of $\pi$ digits

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, random

The following graphic is a 3D "random walk" of $\pi$ digits  by converting them in base $6$ representing $6$ directions :

```
Manipulate[d = N[Pi, n];
walk = First@RealDigits[d, 6]; 
coord = FoldList[Plus, {0, 0, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0,0}, {0, 0, 1}, 
{0, 0, -1}}[[# + 1]] & /@ walk]; 

Graphics3D[{Line[coord], PointSize[Large], Green, Point[First@coord], Red, 
Point[Last@coord]}, ImageSize -> 400], {n, 1, 100000, 1}]
```

[image]

There is a $257019$ lines (`First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 200000], 6] // Length`)

and I want to colorize each  direction by six color

```
colors = {Red, Blue, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Purple}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll leave it to other people to make a longer path out of this:

```
walkRules = AssociationThread[Range[0, 5], {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0},
                                            {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}];
colorRules = AssociationThread[Range[0, 5], {Red, Blue, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Purple}];

digits = First[RealDigits[π, 6, 10^3]];
coord = FoldList[Plus, {0, 0, 0}, Lookup[walkRules, digits]];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], {Green, Point[First[coord]]}, {Red, Point[Last[coord]]}, 
            Riffle[Lookup[colorRules, digits], Line /@ Partition[coord, 2, 1]]},
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: colored \pi walk]

Comment: `digits` are not defined and `walkRules` not used. I guess you have a line missing.

Comment: Whoops. Check now, please.

Comment: I am sorry for the down-vote but this is not right.  All the segments are gradients: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40RTs.png

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, luckily, it's easy to fix.

Comment: Happy to reverse my vote :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
segments = {coord[[;; -2]], coord[[2 ;;]]}\[Transpose];
selectColor[a_List, b_List] :=
 Which[
  a[[1]] > b[[1]], Red,
  a[[1]] < b[[1]], Blue,
  a[[2]] > b[[2]], Green,
  a[[2]] < b[[2]], Cyan,
  a[[3]] < b[[3]], Yellow,
  a[[3]] > b[[3]], Purple
  ]
Graphics3D[{selectColor @@ #, Line@#} & /@ segments]
```

[image]